# Create DropDown in Magento frontend view

Tags: magento

I have a custome module who allow add custom records to sql from backend and edit.

How to call dropdown for forntend view block.

Simple records view grid in admin:

```
ID  Title Value
1   name1 value1
2   name2 value2
```

In view have:

```
<?php echo Mage::getModel('module/block')->getSelectBox(); ?>
```

In Model folder have function:

```
public function getSelectBox(){

return  'test';

}
```

How call dropdown in this function who select all records from backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use collection. You can fetch all value anywhere this way.

```
$coll = Mage::getModel('module/block')->getCollection();
foreach($coll as $value){
    print_r($value->getData());
}
```

To use getSelectBox to return array of title=>value

```
public function getSelectBox(){
    $coll = $this->getCollection();
    $response = array();
    foreach($coll as $value){
        $response[$value->getTitle()]=$value->getValue();
    }
    return  $response;
}
```